# What's the meaning of "concave" in this context?

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of "concaved" in this senctence:

> As long as voters’ utility functions are ***concave***, voters prefer policies that do not change drastically.

Answer (score 3):

Concave here retains it's original meaning:

> curved like the inner surface of a sphere or bowl

(Wiktionary)

A utility function is a type of mathematical function which is used in economics. The graph of this function can be sloped. The type of slope concave or convex. An example of a concave utility function is this, from Wikipedia:

[image]

Try googling "Utility Function concave". You can even check out [Risk Aversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion).

Comment: That looks convex to me.  Concave is dented inward in the center.

Answer (score 0):

A concave function is a type mathematical function (a curve). In economics a Utility function describes risk aversion. A concave utility function describes a risk-averse individual.

You can simplify that sentence to: "as long as voters don't like taking big risks, they prefer policies that do not change much"